# Do different species create offspring (NEAT)?

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms

So I'm implementing [NEAT in Javascript](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic), however i'm not sure if different species should crossover.

[image]

So what i'm understanding is that offspring will only be created from parents originating from the same species, however is that always the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends mostly on whether you want it to or not. Stanley and Miikkulainen do leave this pretty open, but in the NEAT C++ code which accompanies the paper, there is a parameter named `interspecies_mate_rate` which is often very low (around %0.1). Also, there is the parameter for `stolen_babies` which is usually disabled, but would also introduce interspecies breeding.

So to answer your question, you can get away with no interspecies breeding, but the theory of adding it, is that it *could* allow allow the best of both species to merge.

(It also models what occasionally occurs in nature, and is an interesting consideration)